# What does $S^z$ mean for each $z\in\mathbb{C}$?

Tags: soft-question, category-theory

> Let $S$ be a set. What does $S^z$ mean for each $z\in\mathbb{C}$?

In Set Theory numbers are sets and for any two sets $A$ and $B$, we define $B^A$ as the set of maps from $A$ to $B$. *Well okay*, but I don't **understand** what $S^z$ would mean (if anything) for $z\in\mathbb{C}\setminus\mathbb{N}$, where $0\notin\mathbb{N}$.

### My Attempt.

I suppose $S^{0}=\emptyset$ would be a sensible guess.

---

Let $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Through Category Theory, in $\mathbf{\text{Set}}$ we can see the Cartesian product of $n$ copies of $S$ via cones in terms of commutative diagrams like so: the product is the cone $$\left(\prod_{r=1}^{n}{S}\stackrel{\pi_{i}}{\to} S\right)_{i=1}^n$$ such that for any cone $$\left(X\stackrel{p_{i}}{\to} S\right)_{i=1}^n$$ there exists a unique $u:X\to\prod_{r=1}^{n}{S}$ such that the following diagrams commute:

[image].

If $z\in \mathbb{R}$ and $z>0$, I suppose we could let $n$ be the integer part $[z]$
 of $z$ in the above and conjure some appropriate $\mathbf{\text{Set}}$-arrow $\pi_{\{z\}}:\prod_{z}{S}\to \bar{S}$ for the fractional part $\{z\}$ of $z$ to get something like

[image].

> I have no idea what $\pi_{\{z\}}:\prod_{z}{S}\to \bar{S}$ should be though.

To illustrate this sketch, if I could order the elements of $S$ with some $<$ to get $S_<$, I suppose I could take the first $\{z\}$ elements of $S_<$. For example, I'd have something like $\{1, 2, 3, 4\}^{2.5}:=\{1, 2, 3, 4\}^2\times\{1, 2\}$ under the natural order.

---

If the above makes sense, I'd try extending this to $z\in\mathbb{R}$ & $z<0$ using coproducts like so:

[image].

(I hope you'll forgive me for not defining things in the diagram immediately above.)

---

I need $S^{-z}\times S^{z}=S^0$.

---

If we return to Set Theory, I suppose we'd need to specify which construction of $\mathbb{R}$ we're using first to make sense of $S^z$ for $z\in\mathbb{R}$.

---

I have no idea what to make of $z\in\mathbb{C}\setminus\mathbb{R}$.

> **Is any of this making sense?**

Comment: So, I guess you want to generalize the "cartesian product" to non-integer powers.  So, perhaps the first thing to do is define $S^{1/2}$ somehow.  If $|S|=2$, does that mean $S^{1/2}$ should have $|S^{1/2}| = \sqrt{2}$ ??

Comment: Actually, $S^0$ should have one element, not zero elements.

Comment: I'm not sure about that take on $S^0$, @GEdgar. Please explain it :)

Comment: Oops: for the $z\in\mathbb{R}$ & $z<0$ case, I'd need a few absolute values . . . Sorry! I'll correct that tomorrow. I don't have time just yet.

Comment: Frankly, no, none of this makes any sense. Not everything is begging to be generalised.

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/198514/canonical-pi-dimensional-space

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/73470/104041).

Answer (score 4):

You probably don't want to read this and this is not really an answer, but your idea of defining $S^z$ for complex $z$ just doesn't make any sense. You can draw as many diagrams as you wish, this doesn't matter. Even for $z \in \mathbb{Z}$ there is no way to define $S^z$. The only [invertible object](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/invertible+object) in the monoidal category of sets is the one-point set, and of course $1^z=1$ is not really a discovery.

Comment: *"You probably don't want to read this"* - You're wrong. This is much more *beautiful* than the messy scenario I had in mind. **Thank you!** :D