# Are there $\pi$ -Dimension?

Tags: differential-topology

Are there $\pi$ -Dimension ? When I was thinking of dimensions such as about n-balls. I asked myself why isn't there a $\pi$-Ball. we always talk about n being a natural number. I know the illustration is difficult but the same applies for the 4th or 5th dimension. Thank you very much.

Comment: Consider this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractal_dimension

Comment: Ahh thank you. Didn’t know that, great!

Comment: @Sonal_sqrt So, what is a $\pi$ dimensional ball?

Comment: @Berci: That would be a metric space homeomorphic to, say, $B^3$, and having Hausdorff dimension equal to $\pi$.

Comment: The "[Canonical π dimensional space?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/198514/318073)" is essential this question, but not specifically about a ball. The [answer there](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2385876/318073) gives examples of $\pi$-dimensional (in the sense of fractal dimension aka Hausdorff dimension) objects. For some examples of fractal dimensions $\in[0,3]$ see [this wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_fractals_by_Hausdorff_dimension).

Comment: @Vepir Thank you! I was not aware of that answer on my old question.